# How can I download and read the downloaded file from URL by Java

Tags: java

I would like to create a connection between two URLs by Java. From one URL I should read information from a .docx file what has to be downloaded from url by Java and later I should send these information to the other URL. I tried to read the .docx by the following way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class CheckList {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String FILE = "https://exampleurl.com/download/2037";
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        String username = "myusername";
        String password = "mypassword";
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(username, password));
        URL url = new URL(FILE);

        InputStream content = (InputStream) url.getContent();

        try{

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String str;
         while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(str);
         }
        }catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}


    }

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String login, password;

    public MyAuthenticator(String user, String pass) {
      login = user;
      password = pass;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      System.out.println("Requesting Host  : " + getRequestingHost());
      System.out.println("Requesting Port  : " + getRequestingPort());
      System.out.println("Requesting Prompt : " + getRequestingPrompt());
      System.out.println("Requesting Protocol: "
          + getRequestingProtocol());
      System.out.println("Requesting Scheme : " + getRequestingScheme());
      System.out.println("Requesting Site  : " + getRequestingSite());
      return new PasswordAuthentication(login, password.toCharArray());
    }
  }

}
```

But unfortunately it reads just the javaScript code of the website (the first page where the user has to login). Can someone suggest me a solution?

Comment: It's probably a question of getting the right URL - the javascript could generate that dynamically and issue the request. One way to find that would be to use the developer/debug mode of your favorite browser and view the URLs actually requested. Pick the one that requests the docx file.

Comment: I don't know the Authenticator class very well, but it can't possibly be used to fill in a custom form displayed by the remote web site to authenticate. It's probably rather used for network authentication required by proxies/firewalls, or maybe for basic authentication, but not for custom, web-based authentication. Especially not one using JavaScript.